# SL1 Punchy Pyromancer build help

Tags: dark-souls

So for my 6th playthrough of Dark Souls, I decided that I'm going to make what I call a "punchy pyromancer" (alliteration!). Because I'm planning to use a lightning Caestus on my right hand and pyromancy on my left hand, I thought it would be fun to do an SL1 playthrough.

My question is: having never done an SL1 playthrough before, what is the fastest way for me to get both decent fast-rollable armor (with Havel's ring) and rescue Laurentius? If there is a way to avoid the Capra Demon until I get Combustion that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot rescue Laurentius without killing the Capra Demon. You can however, use the master key to skip to Blighttown, summon a player who has a +10 pyro flame, and then buy combusion from Quelana of Izalith.

To quickly get Havel's ring, use the master key in the Under Burg or run through Darkroot.

For armor, to SL 1 fastroll with Havel's ring, you are looking at just wearing a helmet and some gauntlets from any heavy armor set. Most are pretty similar but elite knight set is available in the Garden, before the Moonlight Butterfly. You can also buy pieces of the chain mail set from the undead merchant in the Undead Burg to hold you over for the first couple areas.

Comment: Some additional advice for the OP: look up "Emarrel" on YouTube. He is a god-tier Souls player and has made a SL1 NG+7 playthrough, amongst many other things. You might find some helpful techniques there, although his videos aren't very instructional and are purely for entertainment value. I'm willing to bet that you will get some decent info from the comment sections on those videos though.

Comment: Wow, didn't know Quelaana would appear when a summon had +10 pyro, that's definitely good to know. Great answer.